# How to use the ($) operator correctly

Tags: haskell, syntax

These lines execute correctly:

```
Prelude> 1 / (1 + 1)
0.5
Prelude> (/) 1 $ (+) 1 1
0.5
Prelude> (/) 1 $ 1 + 1
0.5
```

This one does not:

```
Prelude> 1 / $ (+) 1 1

<interactive>:1:4: parse error on input `$'
```

Why?

Comment: You can use an operator "section" to do this: `(1 /) $ (+) 1 1`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

/ is an infix operator. It requires valid expression on both its sides. `1` is a literal and thus a valid expression. However, on right-hand side you have immediately another infix operator, which requires to be preceded by another valid expression (and `1 /` is not a valid expression, as it lacks right-hand side argument to the / operator). This is why parser reports error (invalid grammar — see haskell report for ugly details ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is because `$` is an operator that requires a function preceding it.  The expression `1 /` in your last example does not evaluate to a function.  In that case, the parser is expecting to find a (numeric) expression as the second argument to the `/` operator.

Comment: What you describe is a semantical explanation, and ghci returns parser error — that's a syntactic error. (Note: I am not arguing that that code should work ;)